# firefoxprofile not working if firefoxbinary is set as webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary)

Tags: python, selenium, user-agent, tor, selenium-firefoxdriver

I noticed if I use `firefox_binary` within `webdriver`, the `firefox_profile` is not **working.im** getting my standard `useragent`.

```
profile = FirefoxProfile(r".\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default")
binary = FirefoxBinary(r".\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe")
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", userAgent)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary)
```

But if use `driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)` I see the updated useragent but then normal firefox is opening with my standard **ip**.

What am i doing wrong?
my os is on `Windows 11` and **Python 3.9.9**

I also see, when im using the webdriver with firefox_binary right of address bar "not connected" but the website for example  `https://api.ipify.org` is showing another **IP** always. is that a problem?
if I use `webdriver` without `firefox_binary` is see nothing right of the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue that you are declaring profile as a variable twice:

```
profile = FirefoxProfile(r".\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default")

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
```

Amend to the following:

```
prof = FirefoxProfile(r".\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default")

profile = webdriver.prof
```